# Bootstrap navbar two groups

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, and now I have this HTML code for Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-brand">Menu</div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Contacts", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Now I would like to add there a SearchBox with the Search-icon, which will be on the right side of the nav bar, but when the navbar is "packed" into Hamburger button, I would like this Search Box to be "packed" into Search-icon-button, which would appear right-side from Hamburger button.

Comment: Use the `pull-right` class for the navbar with the search field: http://jsfiddle.net/ge11hq07/

Comment: I think that does not help, unless I've misunderstood you.

Comment: You should add a JSFiddle showing exactly the problem. The question is quite confusing

Comment: http://i57.tinypic.com/2llykc8.png ... On the top there is what I have.. on the bottom is what I would like to have, but I am not able to do it.

Comment: My HMLT code, which I posted above is exactly showing what I have (just the A elements are a little different.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ge11hq07/1/

Comment: Well, It seems that we are approaching, but still not working. When I click on the Search-icon, nothing happens, and when I click Hamburger-icon, there is also the Search Box and the Button, which is not good.

Comment: Well, I think you can go from here. I'm not doing your job. Try yourself and if you can't, show what you got and I'll be happy to help